# APEX: How do I make a button set values of other items?

Tags: events, button, onclick, oracle-apex

I have some drop-down filters for my reports.
I want to make a button to `Clear All Filters` when the user clicks it.

[image]

This button needs to:

1. Set the values of the drop-down items to their static default values (the default is 'ALL')
2. Submit the page? (I presume, so that the reports can reload with the new filter values)

How do you set the values of other items from a button click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a process which will set items' default values, e.g.

```
:P1_FISCAL_QUARTER := 'ALL';
:P1_FREQUENCE      := 'ALL';
```

Its (button's) default action is "Submit" anyway; just set this process to run when `P1_BTN_CLEAR_ALL` (if that's its name)  button is pressed.